# Why is this valid boolean b = new A() {} instanceof A; if A is an abstract class?

Tags: java, object-oriented

I have trouble understanding why this `boolean b = new A() {} instanceof A;` is a valid statement and not `boolean b = new A() instanceof A;` and why the former is true knowing that A is an abstract class.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `instanceof A` has nothing to do with whether the statement is valid or not, so your question is simpler if you leave it off from both statements:

```
A a = new A() {};
A a = new A();
```

The second statement isn't valid because `A` is abstract and you can't call `new` on any abstract class. If you could instantiate it, it would be an instance of `A`, but you can't.

The first statement is valid because it creates an [anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that extends `A`. This anonymous class isn't abstract (assuming `A` doesn't define any abstract methods), and so it can be instantiated.  It's an instance of `A` because all subclasses are instances of their parent classes, abstract or not. It's basically a shortcut for saying:

```
public class AnonymousNameIDontCareAbout extends A {}
A a = new AnonymousNameIDontCareAbout();
```